# Concerning the definition of a 2-crossed module

Tags: higher-category-theory, higher-algebra, gerbes, holonomy, crossed-modules

**Question:**

*Is there some generalization of the definition of crossed-module which appropriately fits into the holonomy-considerations I am interested in and has, as an example, the generalization of the crossed module $(Ad: G \to Aut(G), ev)$ mentioned below?*

---

**Context:**

I want to generalize the definition of crossed module, $(t:H\to  G, \alpha)$, to one higher dimension since I would like to try and extend some of my ideas from 2-holonomy for a non-abelian gerbe with connection, up one dimension higher.

I am aware that there are definitions such as [this one](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/2-crossed+module), which seem to be inspired by looking at maps of chain complexes.  In particular, in that definition, the map $\{ -, -\} : M \times M \to L$ makes sense if $M$ is degree $-1$ maps and $L$ is degree $-2$ maps and so $\{-, -\}$ is just a bracket of pairs of maps.  While it does have the nice "boundary squared is zero" condition which mimics the geometry, this definition does not seem to make sense in the context of higher holonomy, since a pair of $2$-holonomy values (in $M$) should not uniquely lift to a  $3$-holonomy value (in $L$).

The example of a crossed module I would like to generalize is $(inn: G \to Aut(G), ev)$.  Clearly, we can form chains of groups arbitrarily long where each pair is a crossed module:

$$ G \to Aut(G) \to Aut(Aut(G)) \to \dots  $$

but (unless I'm making a silly error) we no longer have the condition that "boundary squared is zero".  Also notice that it is not clear that there is a non-trivial map, $\{ -, -\}: Aut(G) \times Aut(G) \to G$, so I'm not sure this example fits into the referenced definition of 2-crossed module.

Comment: Not sure it would help, but see https://arxiv.org/abs/0708.1741 (maybe the moral is that you want crossed squares rather than 2-crossed modules?)

Comment: Thank you, I will look into this.

Comment: @DavidRoberts on page 23, since I thought I might be interested in "inner automorphism 3-groups" I saw that it seems to be based on the notion of the crossed module (id: G->G, inn.).  I think non-abelian gerbes with this crossed module might all be "trivial" in the sense that they are 1-connected to the trivial gerbe with that crossed module.  Hence I'm wary of ideas using that as a jump-off point!

Comment: Sure, but a crossed square is in some respects a crossed module of crossed modules. Given a crossed module there is a monoidal groupoid of self-equivalences of the corresponding strict 2-group, with potentially weak inverses. One could strictify this to get a strict 2-group, hence a crossed module, and a crossed module acts on itself by conjugation, so should give a map Ad. Alternatively, consider all strictly invertible endomorphisms, and skip strictification.

Comment: There is probably work of Ronnie Brown or others of the Bangor school of automorphims of crossed modules and the combination with crossed squares. I'd have to dig through the papers and see, but I vaguely recall seeing some of this, perhaps in some PhD thesis, or work by a postdoc in the 1980s.

Comment: @DavidRoberts No need to dig.  I really appreciate your comments.  I just think I can generalize some things I did with 2-holonomy in the setting I described above but the referenced definition was a bit more cumbersome while trying to do the same work.

Comment: I'd be interested to know what 2-holonomy you have worked on, if you want to contact me elsewhere.

Comment: @DavidRoberts I believe I contacted you elsewhere.

Comment: yes, sorry, just replied before I saw this...